# java arrayoutofbounds exception error when program together

Tags: java, arrays, exception, error-handling

I am doing an assignment and I have to do several simple string manipulations. I think I have the last one figured out, and it works by itself, but it does not work when I put it together with the other string manipulations, giving me an arrayoutofbounds exception error. Any advice?
Here is the small code I made

```
  public static void main (Strings[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String theSentence = sc.nextLine();
    String [] theWords = theSentence.split(" ");
    Arrays.sort(theWords);
    System.out.println(theWords[1]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(theWords));
}
```

This does not work when it is put together with the rest of the code even though it works by itself. For reference, this code is supposed to take in a small sentence and give me the smallest word lexicographically. Ex: input: `"4 WHAT WAIT IS THIS"` output would be `"IS"`

Comment: It's better to show the code which doesn't work.

Comment: this is the code that has an error on the line     "System.out.println(theWords[1])'

Comment: @EricGrube No, this code works perfectly with the input you gave us.

Comment: You should write every error message you get.

Comment: that's my problem it works fine by itself, but when i throw it at the end of my main program it gives me the error. I don't want to upload the whole code as it is an assignment that other students in my class could be looking for online and don't want to help them cheat.

Comment: @EricGrube If you want our help you **must** show us the buggy code, (and not the code that works) describing _what_ doesn't work and showing us the full stack trace. If you don't want to paste here the code we can't help you.

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` happens when you try to access an index in an array that doesn't exist, i.e. the index is greater than (or equal to, becase indices begin at 0) the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 7):

The code is assuming that `theWords` will always have at least two elements in it. If the sentence provided by the user does not have any spaces, `theWords` will never get an element in position 1 and so the program will crash on `System.out.println(theWords[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

In Java arrays are indexed from zero, where the 0th element is the first.
As Mark said you are assuming that there are always two words entered in this case. You should check the length of theWords before trying to access an element.